# matching the frame identifier of a limited file sequence with regex

Tags: regex

I have some code that can use regex to filter and find a list of files.

I want to filter these files by their name, and select the final set of numbers in the filename.

for example, say I have this sequence of file names:

`render1frame0001.png ... render1frame0200.png`

Finding the last 4 digits isnt that hard. The issue is when the file name itself has numbers in it.

Some platforms have different margins for frame counts, so I need it to be able to match more or less than 4 characters, while also ignoring any numbers in the file name.

so in the example above, it would match `0001` through `0200`, ignoring the `1` inside the filename.

I dont have much experience with regex and this particular problem seems a little niche, so I dont exactly know what to do here.

also, the files can possibly have other extensions, such as jpeg, so I guess it should also be able to work around different extensions.

**Essentially I want to match the first occurrence of a group of numbers... but from the end of the string backwards. That behavior could possibly get around the extension and any extra numbers in the file name.**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used "Lookahead and Lookbehind" to get numeric value properly.
regex = `/(?<=\w+)\d+(?=\.[a-z]+)/gi` (Best) or `/\d+(?=\.[a-z]+)/gi` or `/\d+(?=\.[a-z]+$)/gi` (if you pass single file name at a time).

Your Input is: "render1frame0001.png ... render1frame0200.png".
You have to match numbers before file format ('.png').

[image]
[image]

For more details about regular expression follow this: [Puzzling with Regular Expression](https://medium.com/@artbindu/puzzling-with-regular-expression-d2f6cc1d1976)

Answer (score 0):

Since each string is a filename that include the file extension, you should be able to use the below regular expression, regardless of the file type:

`(\d+)\.[a-z]+$`

[Regular Expression Tests](https://regex101.com/r/kPAiwA/1)

*Note: since the regular expression contains the `$` character, each filename should be parsed individually.*

Comment: thankyou, thats exactly what I needed. when the question allows me to accept an answer I will.